# How to call a user connected from multiple devices in ApiRTC?

Tags: webrtc

If I initialize the same user connected from multiple devices with the same **apiCCId**, when I try to call him, only one of the devices manages to start the call.

How can I deal with situation like that? Maybe I need to use JOIN / LEAVE room instead of calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have same user connected on multiple device, this user will receive call notification on all devices.
The first device where the call is accepted will make the call cancel on others devices (This is call forking).

You can check following tutorial to activate accept / refuse calls on apiRTC Client :
https://apirtc.com/tutos/Video_client_Material/apiRTC-Material-Client-Video-AcceptRefuse.html

Comment: Could you quote in your answer any relevant parts of the linked resource? As-is, your answer is very susceptible to link rot (i.e. it would be much less useful if the linked page breaks), which is bad for Stack Overflow.